# Regular expression to remove everything which is inside a specific pattern including the pattern itself. Remove latex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, nlp, python-re

I want to remove two very specific kind of patterns one for latex and one for capital words but the problem is that there is a huge variation and I have no idea how to remove these.

First kind of pattern which is relatively easy and removes every latex info from the text. IF my text looks like

**1.**

```
'hello \( [\mathrm{BHU} \cdot 05, \cdot 06] \) my name'  #(very common)
or 
hello\( [\mathrm{BHU} \cdot 05, \cdot 06] \)my name #(rare)
```

I want it to be simply `'hello my name'`

I used `re.sub("/(\s*",'', 'fsdfv  //(')`
but it is showing `error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 1`

Also there is a catch. There is something li `\text` and I want to preserve that info.
For ex:

```
\( \begin{array}{ll}\text { 34. Crossing over helps in } & \text { [AFMC'02] }\end{array} \)
```

I want to keep `34. Crossing over helps in` and `[AFMC'02]`

**2.**:
Second looks something like given below and is an extension of above problem

```
[AFMC'02]
[ AFMC 2011 ]
[MHCET 2004; J \& K CET 2008]
{AIEEE}
{ IIT-JEE }
{ U.P.T.U. }
(UPTU)
```

There are also equations like `(x-y)*3=2` but the above problem only has upper case letters and the equations have small case.

How can I remove these patterns from my data. These are acting like garbage values in my NLP problems and I don not know how to remove these. Please help.

Comment: For the first example you can use `\s*\\\(.*?\\\)\s*` https://regex101.com/r/sJ1yMT/1 and for the second example you can use `\[[^][]*]|{[^{}]*}` https://regex101.com/r/8DSy24/1

Comment: If you want a single pattern, you can use 2 capturing groups. If group 1 is a match, replace with a space. If group 2 is a match, replace with an empty string. `(\s*\\\(.*?\\\)\s*)|(\[[^][]*]|{[^{}]*})` https://regex101.com/r/mERtk3/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird can you please check the update. I want to preserve `\text` value

Comment: You might do it in 2 passes https://ideone.com/Cd3WF7

Comment: But how do you preserve the inner while removing the outer. I get you idea and code but how to preserve `\text {}` when this itself is inside the thing I want to remove?

Comment: In this case you could use a capturing group to select what you want to keep, and select the rest that you don't want. Then use the group in the replacement.